# should I use hasOne or hasMany?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have my **"users"** table. I want to associate this table with 5 other tables.

```
"Contact_info", "Education_info", "Job_info", "Hobby_info", "Bio_info".
```

I'm using [sequelize.js](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) at the moment.

Right now I'm using **"hasOne"** because my user can only have

```
1 "contact_info", 

1 "education_info", 

2 "job_info", 

1 "Hobby_info",

and 1 "Bio_info".
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: have you tried ... reading the docs / researching?

Comment: well if the user can have or should have one record relation of the those other tables then yes `hasOne` relation sounds correct.

Comment: yeah, that's why I'm using "hasOne". I know I'll use "belongsTo" for my user's table because "contact_info" belongsTo one user. and one user can only haveOne contact info.

Comment: thanks @RaymondNijland I just wanted someone else opinion. I don't understand why treyBake would assume I didn't read the docs.

Comment: Some poeple here have prejudices and don't care to ask more questions to get more information about what know or don't know or have researched or not.. Because ideally the information should be in the question see the [helpdesk](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)